# Is it possible to change the font color of only the first option in a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using Select2js plugin, is it possible to change only the first option's font color in the select element?

**I have tried…**

```
select option:first-child { color:red; }
```

**and**

```
$(function() {
    $("select option:first-child").addClass("red");
});

.red { color:red; }
```

**Example:**

```js
$(function() {
    $("select").select2();
  $("select option:first-child").addClass("red");
});
```

```css
.red {color: red;}
select option:first-child {color: red;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Text 1</option>
  <option>Text 2</option>
  <option>Text 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Fiddles are great, but for most things, use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) right here on-site instead, so that all of the content of your question is **in** your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right-click the select2 options and choose "Inspect" (or "Inspect Element", depending on your browser), you'll see that they aren't `option` elements, they're `li` elements with the class `select2-results__option` in a `ul` with the class `select2-results__options`.

So:

```
.select2-results__options li.select2-results__option:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyd2dsfL/4/), or as a Stack Snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").select2();
  $("select option:first-child").addClass("red");
});
```

```css
.select2-results__options li.select2-results__option:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select>
  <option>Text 1</option>
  <option>Text 2</option>
  <option>Text 3</option>
</select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
```

If you like, you can further refine the styling for active elements using the class `select2-results__option--highlighted`, which is added when elements are "active." For instance, here I've made it blue when it's not active, and red when it is:

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").select2();
  $("select option:first-child").addClass("red");
});
```

```css
.select2-results__options li.select2-results__option:first-child {
  color: blue;
}
.select2-results__options li.select2-results__option.select2-results__option--highlighted:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select>
  <option>Text 1</option>
  <option>Text 2</option>
  <option>Text 3</option>
</select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
```